# How reliable are modern databases in the presence of disk errors?

Tags: database, reliability, interbase, stability

> InterBase had an architecture that caused disk-writes to leave the database in an always-consistent state
>   -- *97 things every software architect should know*, p87

Is this property finally common in 2010 ?

Is there a study about database stability/reliability in presence of disk errors ?

Comment: The title and the text do not agree. The title is S&A almost by definitions. There may be an acceptable question in the text, but even that is unclear. Are you asking about assuring consistency (like many modern filesystems do), or about behavior in the presence of *errors in the hardware performance*? Two different problems. Voted to close for the moment, but could be persuaded to vote to reopen if the question is clarified and the flame bait is removed.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable database is, without a doubt DB2. But not that toy LUW thing you run under UNIX and Windows.

I'm talking about the big grunter, DB2/z, the one that runs on the mainframe.

Quake in terror, all you puny, non-mainframe, database wannabes :-)

By the way, the *reason* it's so reliable is the underlying hardware. Non-mainframe platforms can only *dream* of the sorts of redundancy levels and self-checking that goes on in the System z boxes.

Comment: a commodity hardware cluster has high redudancy. for lower price ?

Comment: @user: a well designed, assembled, configured and maintained cluster has a enough redundancy to be compared to big iron. A lot of times the comparison goes "While cheaper than a mainframe a cluster still doesn't have...", but it is close enough that comparing them makes sense. The thing is the guys who can set it up that way are as rare and expensive as big iron sysadmins, and it is easy to mess up.

Answer (score 0):

Interbase is still alive and Interbase free fork is [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html)